# Python: map two arrays with similar values

Tags: python, list, numpy, performance, loops

I have two arrays, lets say A and B. I want to find all elements in B that are within a certain value of all elements in A.

To be exact, I am working with database of galaxies and I want to compare simulated galaxies (S) with observed (O).
I have 2 arrays: brightness (Br) and distance (D) for both simulated and observations. (so 4 arrays in total)
for each simulated galaxy, i want to find a set of galaxies from the observed list, that has similar brightness and distance.

I have already made a code that could work but my program says it will take around 9-10 hours to run the code. Is there any other way I can efficiently change the code to speed up the process:

Here is my code

```
list1= flux_hb
list2= flux_inp_ha

flux_MC=[[]]*len(list1) # map flux from MAMBO to COSMOS (mambo--> (list of cosmos galaxies))
noise=[[]]*len(list1)
z_MC=[[]]*len(list1)

index=np.zeros(len(list1))
flux_ha_temp=np.zeros(len(list1))

for i in tqdm(range(len(list1))):
    
    temp_flux_diff = abs(list1[i] - list2)/list1[i] #Matrix subtraction
    temp_z_diff = abs(z_geo[i] - zinp)/z_geo[i]
    
    for j in range(len(temp_flux_diff)):
        
        if (temp_flux_diff[j]<0.01 and temp_z_diff[j]<0.01):
            flux_MC[i].append(list2[j])
            noise[i].append(snr_ha[j])
            z_MC[i].append(zinp[j])
```

My approach is to make an empty list to save the information I need.

1. For each element in list1, find the difference in values of list1 from list2 (temp_flux_diff)
2. Now for each element in list2, if any of this difference is smaller than required difference, i call them similar values and save them in the empty list.

Hopefully, I was able to explain what I need and how I did it. I just want to speed up the code.

**Update 1** As per the suggestion in comments by @СергейКох, i changed my second loop to:

```
index = np.where(np.logical_and(temp_flux_diff<0.01, temp_z_diff<0.01))[0]

flux_MC[i].append(flux_inp_ha[index])
noise[i].append(snr_ha[index])
z_MC[i].append(zinp[index])
```

and my code now takes around 1 hour instead of 9 hours.

Comment: Use numpy functions for your calculations, not loops.

Comment: @СергейКох Which numpy functions can I use for this?

Comment: @СергейКох ok, I changed the second loop to argument 
'index = np.where(np.logical_and(temp_flux_diff<0.01, temp_z_diff<0.01))[0]'
and it significantly sped up the code. 9 hours --> 1 hour
thank you